# reverse proxy mulitple ipython notebook servers

Tags: nginx, ipython, jupyter-notebook, reverse-proxy

Currently we are running an Ipython notebook server behind a nginx proxy. This works well as it is a straightforward 1-to-1 mapping.

Now we want to run multipe notebook servers behind 1 proxy. Since these servers will be dynamically added, the proxying should be dynamic as well.

Ideally I'd like to proxy on a url subpath:

```
http://open.net/py1 -> http://secure1:8888
http://open.net/py2 -> http://secure2:8888
http://open.net/py3 -> http://secure3:8888
etc.
```

Problem with this approach is that Ipython doesn't use relative url's inside it's html. extract:

```
<script src="/static/.../promise.min.js"</script>
<script src="/static/.../require.js"</script>
<script> ...
```

So inside http://open.net/py2 `require.js` will be loaded via `http://open.net/static/.../require.js` which of course will result in a 502. It should be `http://open.net/py2/static/.../require.js`

**Question**: what's a good strategy to solve this?

**Constraints**:

- I cannot touch the source html
- I cannot use subdomains for each Ipython server (as they are dynamically added)

Comment: How you match that `/py3` should proxy to `secure3`?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a regex...To be clear: it's not like that for now, this is only a hypothesis. I would like to proxy on subpath because the alternative (AFAIK) is adding subdomains on the fly, which is tedious imo.

Comment: You don't need to add subdomains every time. Just add wildcard subdomain and have nginx to listen to any subdomain.

Comment: I previously talked this through with our devops guys. They have a bad feeling in their stomachs about regex routing on a wildcard subdomain (security holes). But yea, so be it. tx!

Comment: Well they right for some point. But you could easily restrict subdomains to something like `py\d+`, so `weak.example.com` will not match and goes to some other server

Comment: You can change the base URL the IPython notebook server uses by setting `NotebookApp.base_url` in config. [Jupyterhub](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub) already does something very similar to this - exposing multiple independent notebook users behind a single proxy.

Comment: I will try that as well. tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's a good strategy to solve this?

Subdomains

> I cannot use subdomains for each Ipython server (as they are dynamically added)

Not true.

```
# this will only py<some-digits> subdomain.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<sub>py\d+)\.example\.com$;
    # now you have $sub variable that contains subdomain
    # and could be used to choose what server you want to connect
    ...
}

# catch all server block that simple shows 404 for any request
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 404;
}
```